# Resize full disk encryption in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: encryption, 18.04, windows-10

I have installed ubuntu on my 1Tb main HDD and enabled the full disk encryption. Now I need to add dual boot windows 10. How can I "chop off" / reclaim some disk space (lets say 100Gb) to install windows? Is there anything special I need to do or care about because the disk is encrypted?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions and ask if you have a problem

Comment: if you do not have LVM than you can use GParted utility for increase partition but before do this operation, must take copy of your disk and partition table.

Comment: i do have LVM, i'll give it a try

Comment: reading an official guide that has prayer as one of the steps is too scary!!

Comment: That is not an official guide. It's a community guide and it is not very well written and not working either unfortunately. It can't be that uncommon to double boot and have an encrypted harddrive but I haven't found anyone that got it working yet.